# Compare 2 Columns and have to take words which is not in column A using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to compare 2 columns for example

```
select * from table1

Column_1                column_2
----------------        ------------------
Swetha                  Swetha is working in Chennai
Raju                    Raju is studying 10 std
ranjith                 Rantith played yesterday
how to play             how to play Cricket
My name is              my name is john
```

and my output is

```
Column_1                column_2                         column_3
----------------        ------------------               ------------------------
Swetha                  Swetha is working in Chennai     is working in Chennai
Raju                    Raju is studying 10 std          is studying 10 std
ranjith                 Rantith played yesterday         played yesterday
how to play             how to play Cricket              Cricket
My name is              my name is john                  john
```

If a word comes in between it should also remove like below

```
Column_1                column_2
----------------        ------------------
Swetha working          Swetha is working in Chennai
Raju 10th               Raju is studying 10th std
```

Output:

```
Column_1                column_2                         column_3
----------------        ------------------               ------------------------
Swetha working          Swetha is working in Chennai     is in Chennai
Raju 10th               Raju is studying 10th std        is studying std
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: plz check my question now

Comment: Mr.dale I tried a lot but I don't know how can I show my attempt

Comment: Mr.dale I tried to Split words in column A and I compared to column B but I am getting an error plz help if you can

Comment: Add data where part of words may be replaced, like `('Kent', 'Klark Kent went to Kentucky')`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want `replace()`:

```
select t.*, replace(column_2, column_1, '') column_3 from table1 t
```

Comment: If column_1 = Raju working, column_2 = raju is working, then what query to use in order to get the text output "is"?

Comment: I tried above query it is removing only at the beginning, if the duplicate words come in between means it is coming full words from column B to Column_c

Comment: @Tinku . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  You should ask new questions as *new* question, not in comments.  I would recommend that you undo your edit, accept this answer, and ask a new question.  Your edit only serves to invalidate this valid answer on the original question and to discourage anyone else from trying to help (what new issue are you going to come up with after someone else answers?).